# Как поставить пробел внутри PHP кода?

Tags: php, синтаксис

Добрый день, есть сайт на wordpress. Используется `php` код цен, надо было поменять местами цифры и символ валюты, но в итоге убрались пробелы. Читал статьи в интернете, но рушиться сайт, когда вставляю их примеры. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать пробелы:

```
<?php echo esc_html( $salary_min ) ТУТ ; echo get_workscout_currency_symbol() ?> <?php if(!empty($salary_max)) { echo '- '.$salary_max И ТУТ .get_workscout_currency_symbol(); } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так?

```
<?php echo esc_html( $salary_min ).' ' ; echo get_workscout_currency_symbol() ?> <?php if(!empty($salary_max)) { echo '- '.$salary_max.' '.get_workscout_currency_symbol(); } ?>
```

Comment: Совершенно верно, спасибо.

Comment: Рад помочь. Если это правильный ответ, потметьте, пожалуйста, его как правильный (значок галочки).

Answer (score 0):

Помимо конкатенации, вы можете использовать функции форматирования `printf/sprintf`:

```
<?=sprintf('%s %s', esc_html( $salary_min ), get_workscout_currency_symbol())?>
<?php if (!empty($salary_max)) printf(" - %s %s", $salary_max, get_workscout_currency_symbol())?>
```